# Issue with Compiling Go in Windows 64bit

Tags: compiler-construction, compilation, compiler-errors, go

I have installed Go from [gomingw](http://code.google.com/p/gomingw/downloads/list) for windows 64 bit. However, I cannot find out anywhere how to actually compile a .go file. This is the program linked directly from the Go wiki for Windows Support, but all the tutorials talk about using 6g and gccgo etc. and none of those work on my windows machine. Actually, what I am trying to do is, I put my "hello.go" in src folder and after going to src folder I run the command "8g hello.go" in command prompt. But. it showing error "open a.go no such file or directory". Can anybody help me by providing correct steps to compile a go program in Windows? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean 6g and gccgo don't work? How are those failing?

Comment: I followed the steps given in http://golang.org/doc/install.html. Those are for Linux, not for windows. I just download gomingw and install it. After that, I gave those command in my command prompt and all of those giving error "open a.go nosuch file or directory". What I want to know is about the steps which I have to follow to run a .go file. Thanks.

Comment: **Note** this question (and its answer) is *very* outdated and not at all applicable to any Go version from the last several years (in which one would use `go install` or `go build` just like on any other Go installation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Navigate to your source code directory (for example, C:\Arpsss), display the current directory, and display the current directory contents.

```
C:\>cd C:\Arpssss
C:\Arpssss>cd
C:\Arpssss
C:\Arpssss>dir
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Directory of C:\Arpssss
11/28/2011  10:26 AM    <DIR>          .
11/28/2011  10:26 AM    <DIR>          ..
11/28/2011  10:24 AM                73 hello.go
               1 File(s)             73 bytes
               2 Dir(s)   4,949,831,680 bytes free
```

Try to compile a non-existent file named `a.go`.

```
C:\Arpssss>8g a.go
open a.go: No such file or directory
```

This is the error you reported--you tried to compile a file named `a.go` that wasn't in your current directory.

Compile, link, and run the hello.go Go source file in the current directory.

```
C:\Arpssss>8g hello.go
C:\Arpssss>8l -o hello.exe hello.8
C:\Arpssss>hello
Hello, World!
```

The `hello.go` program.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello, World!")
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot peterSO. However, I got following error in execution of the process suggested by you, http://www.imagehousing.com/image/911495  Thanks.