# .go file compilation error for windows 64bit

Tags: compilation, compiler-errors, go

My original question was, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8297054/issue-with-compiling-go-in-windows-64bit). Which was answered by peterSO correctly. However, when I am trying to execute .go program, I found errors like [this](http://www.imagehousing.com/imageupload.php?id=911495)  for program [1](http://golang.org/#package%20main%0A%0Aimport%20%22fmt%22%0A%0Afunc%20main%28%29%20%7B%0A%09fmt.Println%28%22Hello,%20%E4%B8%96%E7%95%8C%22%29%0A%7D%0A) and [this](http://www.imagehousing.com/imageupload.php?id=911512)for program [2](http://golang.org/#package%20main%0A%0A//%20fib%20returns%20a%20function%20that%20returns%0A//%20successive%20Fibonacci%20numbers.%0Afunc%20fib%28%29%20func%28%29%20int%20%7B%0A%09a,%20b%20:=%200,%201%0A%09return%20func%28%29%20int%20%7B%0A%09%09a,%20b%20=%20b,%20a+b%0A%09%09return%20b%0A%09%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Afunc%20main%28%29%20%7B%0A%09f%20:=%20fib%28%29%0A%09//%20Function%20calls%20are%20evaluated%20left-to-right.%0A%09println%28f%28%29,%20f%28%29,%20f%28%29,%20f%28%29,%20f%28%29%29%0A%7D%0A). Can anybody help me about, how can this be solved ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have been installing multiple versions of Go, including `release/release.r60.3` and `weekly.2011-09-01` for `windows 386`. If your `PATH` environment variable points to `8g` for `[windows 386 release.r60.3 10076]` but your `GOROOT` environment variable points to packages for `[windows 386 weekly.2011-09-01 9631]`, you will get the following error.

```
C:\Arpssss> 8g hello.go
hello.go:3: import C:/go/pkg/windows_386/fmt.a: 
object is [windows 386 weekly.2011-09-01 9631] 
expected [windows 386 release.r60.3 10076]
```

Clean up the mess you've created! Uninstall Go. Delete all go installation folders. Install `gowin386_release.r60.3_installer.exe`.

Check your `GOROOT` (for Go packages) and `GOBIN` (for `8g`) environment variables.

```
C:\>set GO
GOBIN=C:/Go/bin
GOROOT=C:/Go
```

Check that `GOBIN` is the only go folder in your `PATH` environment variable. For example,

```
C:\>set PATH
PATH=...;C:/Go/bin;...;
```

where `...` is an ellipsis.